# Cardinality of finite dimensional vector spaces over finite fields.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a finite field with cardinality $|\mathbb{K}| = m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ with finite dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and some base $B = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$.

Then $V$ is a finite set with cardinality $|V| = m^n$.

*Proof.*

We know that $V = \text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = \{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_iv_i: \lambda \in \mathbb{K}\}$.

Since there are only finite vectors in the base and only a finite amount of scalars in the field, there are finite-many linear combinations of them, the exact amount being the cardinality of $V$. With elementary combinatorics it follows:

$|V| = |\mathbb{K} \underbrace{\times \ldots \times }_{n \text{ times}} \mathbb{K}| = |\mathbb{K}^n| = |\mathbb{K}|^n = m^n  \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $V$ is the null space, meaning $V = \{0\}$, then $V$ is finite-dimensional with dimension $n=0$ and the set $V$ is finite with cardinality $m = 1$, and the claim still holds: $|\{0\}| = 1 =1^0= m^n$.

Is this a correct proof? How could I formalize the idea I articulate in the written paragraph?

Comment: Yes. As you start with a basis from which the isomorphism $V\cong K^n$ is obvious, did you try proving that for any field any finitely generated $F$-vector space has a finite basis, thus making it $\cong F^d$ for some $d$ independent of the chosen basis ?

Comment: @reuns what exactly do you mean? As far as I know if there's a finite generator I can if neccessary reduce it until it's linearly independent, making it a base. So $V$ is isomorphic to $F^d$ for $d$ being the length of some base obtained by reducing any finite generator, and in the case in which $F$ is finite it follows that $V$ is finite since there's a bijection? And if $F$ is infinite, $V$ is as well?